# How to configure Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google for ASP.NET MVC 4 in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, google-signin

Trying to configure setup and configure login with Google using  **Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google** in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project with Visual Studio 2012.

I've been following this article:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on and checked others as well and they all refer to placing code in **Startup.cs** file which ASP.NET MVC 4 template does not have.

Is Microsoft Owin library only available for ASP.NET MVC 5 then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a lot easier to accomplish this with ASP.NET MVC5:

in **app_start/Startup.Auth.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook;
using Owin;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;

namespace ui.web
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            /* Local logins */
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/login")
            });

            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            /* Google */
            var googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "clientid",
                ClientSecret = "secret",
            };
            googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
            googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);

            /* Facebook */
            var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AppId = "clientid",
                AppSecret = "secret",
                BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
                UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,location",
            };

            facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);

            AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
        }
 }
}
```

**FacebookBackChannelHandler**

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ui.web.infrastructure.auth
{
    public class FacebookBackChannelHandler : HttpClientHandler
    {
        protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Replace the RequestUri so it's not malformed
            if (!request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("/oauth"))
            {
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("?access_token", "&access_token"));
            }

            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't see startup.cs in my project, what should I do to get it work in MVC5